# How to return response.valid instead of response.d ASP.NET ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, validation

In my asp.net site I need simple WebMethod that returns to jquery ajax:

```
{ "valid": true } or { "valid": false }
```

http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/remote/

for that I use code:

```
public class IsValid
    {
        public bool valid { get; set; }
    }


    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static IsValid ValidUser(string userName)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var jsonData = new IsValid
        {
            valid = true
        };

        if (userName.IsEmpty())
        {
            // it's for other validator.
            return jsonData; 
        }

        User user = DbContext.Entity.Users.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserName == userName.Trim());

        if (user != null)
        {
            jsonData = new IsValid
            {
                valid = false
            };
        }

        return jsonData; 
    }
```

but it returns value in response.d.valid insted of response.valid in js function

```
xhr.then(function(response) {
                dfd.resolve($field, 'remote', response.valid === true || response.valid === 'true', response.message ? response.message : null);
            });
```

How should I change my code to return response.valid ?
Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't look the the `js` object is ever called upon to do anything. What it looks like you want is: `return js.Serialize(jsonData);` (Although jsonData is not JSON data until it has been serialized, so I would strongly recommend renaming it).

Comment: I tried that, in that case in javascript it returns response.valid = "undefined" and in response.d = "{ "valid": true }"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant adjust Framework 3.5 and plus Services not to return ".d". But if you make some changes on coding like that, you can use as response.valid.

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string ValidUser(string userName)
    {
           JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(null);

            jsonData = new IsValid
            {
                valid = false
            };

        return js.Serialize(jsonData);
    }


xhr.then(function(response) {
                response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                dfd.resolve($field, 'remote', response.valid === true || response.valid === 'true', response.message ? response.message : null);
            });
```

Comment: I tried that, in that case in javascript it returns response.valid = "undefined" and in response.d = "{ "valid": true }"

Comment: can you share full xhr expression?